# py2exe no compila el ejecutable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando hacer un ejecutable de un programa hecho en python3.6 pero cuando ejecuto `python setup.py py2exe` me da el siguiente error:

```
running py2exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    console=[{"script": "main.py"}]
  File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 188, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 267, in _run
    builder.analyze()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 160, in analyze
    self.mf.import_hook(modname)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
    module = self._gcd_import(name)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
    return self._find_and_load(name)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
    self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 388, in _scan_code
    for what, args in self._scan_opcodes(code):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 417, in _scan_opcodes
    yield "store", (names[oparg],)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

el codigo en python es:

```
print("Hola mundo")
a = input("su nombre es: ")
print("hola {}".format(a))
```

y el setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    console=[{"script": "main.py"}]
)
```

Comment: py2exe no es compatible con Python 3.6 (ni con 3.5 oficialmente). El problema es que en Python 3.6 se llevaron a cabo cambios muy importantes en el bytecode de CPython para los que py2exe no ha sido preparado, principalmente la implementación del conocido como  "wordcode" de 16 bits (no se ha actualizado desde 2014 de hecho...). O usas Python 3.4 o mejor usa otra opción que esté mantenida y tenga  soporte para Python 3.6 como [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Comment: @FJSevilla el problema es que PyInstaller me da [este error](https://gist.github.com/ragnarok22/1dc86650a19988d27f40ab2fef7f75c7)

Comment: la unica version que tengo instalada es 3.6. Ademas lo instale con pip asi que PyWin32 ya debe estar instalado. Como compruebo si lo tengo? mi Windows esta a 64

Comment: cuando lo ejecuto me abre la consola y me da este error `Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-8

Current thread 0x0000218c (most recent call first):`

Comment: Abre CMD y ejecuta el interprete interactivo con `py -3.6`, después haz `import re` a ver si obtienes el mismo error. Después haz  `import enum` y luego `enum` y muestra lo que te imprime, el problema según el error es que no encuentra el atributo [`enum.IntFlag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntFlag) cuando `enum` es parte de la stdlib desde Python 3.4 y no debería ocurrir esto a no ser que no esté importando el módulo correcto o por alguna razón tengas corrompido éste. ¿En algún momento has instalado https://pypi.org/project/enum34/ por ejemplo?

Comment: no recuerdo si he instalado enum34, pero importo la biblioteca re y enum y todo funciona bien en el cmd, cuando ejecuto enum me imprime `<module 'enum' from 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\enum.py'>` asi que supongo que todo este bien

Comment: ¿Has probado con un ejemplo simple como el mostrado con Py2exe fuera de la localización de tu proyecto actual a ver si también te genera el error? En caso contrario probablemente  tu propio proyecto esté causando el problema (y es lo que creo) al enmascarar el módulo `enum` de la stdlib, por ejemplo modificando inadecuadamente el PYTHONPATH, con un módulo llamado enum.py en tu proyecto, etc. Es fácil reproducir tu error con solo crear un módulo enum.py en el mismo directorio que el módulo principal pasado a PyInstaller.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79356/discussion-between-reinier-hernandez-avila-and-fjsevilla).

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que instale TensorFlow en mi maquina, este tiene una dependencia con enum34, desinstalandolo resolvi el problema. Gracias a @fjsevilla y este [link](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3146) resolvi esto.